# How to force add a <plugin> into classpath?

Tags: spring-boot, maven, pom.xml, artifactory

I want to force download the below jar even if I am using plugin tag.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.sonarsource.scanner.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.9.1.2184</version>
    <configuration>.../.../...</configuration>
</plugin>
```

We can't change this to dependency tag, please suggest a way only with using plugin tag. If we move this plugin inside dependency tag, will won't be able to use configuration. Do we have any flag that can help the plugin tag work exactly same as dependency tag?

Comment: It is very unclear what you asking for

Comment: Let's assume the difference between dependency and plugin tag is that it works exactly the same, but when we use the plugin the JAR is not added to the classpath, right? On the other hand, if we mention the jar inside dependency, it will be added to the classpath. But what I want is to use the plugin and attach/download the sonar maven plugin to the classpath. @Jens

Comment: I just want to download the jar through plugin tag, that's it. It should be downloaded into .m2/ folder. @Jens

Comment: It will be downloaded if you put it into the plugins -section of a pom

Comment: But it is not, it is only downloading when it is kept under dependencies -section of a pom. @Jens

Comment: Where is your `<plugins>` tag located?

Comment: Why do you need it on the classpath? Nonetheless if you want it on the classpath it needs to be a `dependency` in the `dependencies` section. You can still use it as a plugin nonetheless. THe fact that is is marked as a dependency doesn't mean you cannot add it as a plugin as well (or vice versa).

Comment: There are few plugins which has configuration and that can't be moven to dependency. @M.Deinum

Comment: If you want to use it as a dependency it has to be a dependency. Why do you need to have it as a dependency in the first place?

Comment: I don't want to. My purpose is to keep the sonar plugin inside <plugins> with one thing which is the sonar jar should be downloaded as well. @M.Deinum

Comment: It will be downloaded even as a plugin, so I don't see the problem you are having, how else could it execute it in the first place when it wouldn't be downloading. So either you are asking the wrong question or are doing wrong things.

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is that you put your `<plugin>` definition into `<pluginManagement>`. Then it will not be downloaded. But it into `<plugins>` (outside pluginManagement).

Comment: It is not inside <pluginManagement> still not downloading.

Comment: So the plugin is not run when you build your project?